# Python sorting using for loop

Tags: python

I have written a for loop to display names in python idle as shown below.

```
1.SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW22.4.129
2.SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW27.5.168
3.SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW16.5.92
4.SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW20.2.115
5.SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW25.2.149
6.SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW29.5.188
7.SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW36.1.234
8.SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW31.3.201
```

The code I have written to display the above items is

```
for i in data.get('files'):
    new_data = i.get('uri').strip('/')
    platform_display = "{}.{}".format(count,new_data)
    platform_dict[count] = new_data 
    count += 1
    print platform_display
```

I want it to be displayed as

```
1.SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW36.1.234
2.SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW31.3.201
3.SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW29.5.188
```

etc in descending order

Please let me know how can I sort the names

Comment: If it will always be the same format, try splitting on `'WW'` and then parsing the right side as a float and sorting on that

Comment: How about using `sorted(..., reverse=True)`?

Comment: Can you please give me the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l1=[
'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW22.4.129',
'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW27.5.168',
'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW16.5.92',
'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW20.2.115',
'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW25.2.149',
'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW29.5.188',
'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW36.1.234',
'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW31.3.201'
]
l1=sorted(l1, key=lambda x: x.split("WW")[-1],reverse=True)
for i in l1:
  print(i)
```

Output:

```
SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW36.1.234
SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW31.3.201
SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW29.5.188
SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW27.5.168
SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW25.2.149
SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW22.4.129
SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW20.2.115
SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW16.5.92
```

Comment: I think `x.rsplit("WW")` would be more suitable here?

Comment: And in this case whole strings can be compared without splitting. Just like this: `sorted(l1, reverse=True)`

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion @MushifAliNawaz

Answer (score 0):

Just use `reversed sort`.

Lets say all your item in the list called `l`,

```
l=['SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW22.4.129',
 'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW27.5.168',
 'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW16.5.92',
 'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW20.2.115',
 'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW25.2.149',
 'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW29.5.188',
 'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW36.1.234',
 'SRA-D12-TY2-2017WW31.3.201']

sorted(l, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working i am able to sort the list

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

platform_list = []
for i in data.get('files'):
    new_data = i.get('uri').strip('/')
    platform_list.append([new_data.split("WW")[-1],new_data])

first_item = itemgetter(0)
new_list = sorted(platform_list, key = first_item)
counter = 0
for i in new_list:
    counter += 1
    print "%d.%s" %(counter,i[1])
```